# How to I create an array in C# by defining the key and the value of each entry?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create an array where I can read data from a database and then create an array with 2 columns.

To get this done in PHP, here is what I have done

```
private function _getSystemRules()
{
    $rules = $this->db->getDataSet('SELECT SQL_CACHE section_name, privilege_key, privilege_value
                                    FROM user_privileges
                                    WHERE status = 1
                                    ORDER BY section_name');

    foreach($rules as $rule) {
        $this->rolesList[$rule['section_name']][$rule['privilege_key']] = $rule['privilege_value'];
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

The final array will look like this

```
Array
(
    [accounts] => Array
        (
            [can_own_account] => 4
            [can_view_summary] => 64
            [can_update_critical] => 32
            [can_update_important] => 16
            [can_update_basic] => 8
            [can_change_owner] => 2
            [can_use] => 1
        )

    [account_phones] => Array
        (
            [can_add] => 2
            [can_edit] => 8
            [can_change_status] => 4
            [can_view] => 1
            [can_change_primary] => 16
        )

    [contacts] => Array
        (
            [can_change_status] => 16
            [can_change_global] => 8
            [can_add] => 32
            [can_view] => 2
            [can_change_primary] => 1
            [can_edit] => 4
        )

    [manage_accounts] => Array
        (
            [can_use] => 1
            [can_update_owner] => 2
            [can_update_dnc_status] => 4
            [can_update_internally_blocked_status] => 8
        )

    [manage_phone_calls] => Array
        (
            [can_change_owner] => 4
            [can_purge] => 8
            [can_change_due_datetime] => 16
            [can_use] => 1
            [can_approve] => 2
            [can_change_urgency_level] => 32
        )

    [notification] => Array
        (
            [can_use] => 1
        )

    [other_contacts] => Array
        (
            [can_save_contact] => 128
            [can_purge_self_created_notes_only] => 32
            [can_purge_all_notes] => 16
            [can_edit_self_created_notes_only] => 8
            [can_create] => 2
            [can_use] => 1
            [can_edit_all_notes] => 4
            [can_save_note] => 64
        )

    [phone_calls] => Array
        (
            [can_use] => 1
            [can_view] => 2
            [can_own_phone] => 4096
            [can_view_client_history] => 2048
            [can_view_history] => 1024
            [can_unpurge] => 512
            [can_edit_completed] => 256
            [can_complete_owned_only] => 64
            [can_edit_open] => 128
            [can_complete_any] => 32
            [can_purge] => 16
            [can_insert] => 8
            [can_update] => 4
            [can_create_call_for_others] => 8192
            [can_create_new_call] => 16384
        )

    [phone_call_views] => Array
        (
            [can_use] => 1
            [can_create] => 2
            [can_list_active] => 4
            [can_list_inactive] => 8
            [can_edit] => 16
            [can_disable] => 32
            [can_enable] => 64
        )

    [system_security] => Array
        (
            [can_change_client] => 1
        )

    [voice_of_client] => Array
        (
            [can_edit] => 4
            [can_submit] => 2
            [can_use] => 1
            [can_purge] => 8
            [can_view_completed] => 16
        )

)
```

Based on the feedback below I am trying to use the Dictionary Class

This is my current code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace POS
{
    class Roles
    {
        static readonly Regex binary = new Regex("^[01]{1,32}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        private Dictionary<string, string[]> permissionList = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();


        public Roles()
        {
            this._definePermissions();
        }

        private int _BinToInt(string str)
        {
            int val = -1;

            if (binary.IsMatch(str))
            {
                val = Convert.ToInt32(str, 2);
            }

            return val;
        }

        private string _IntToBin(int number)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(number, 2);
        }

        private void _definePermissions()
        {
            var db = new dbConnetion();

            string sql =   " SELECT SQL_CACHE sectionName, permissionKey, permissionValue "
                         + " FROM role_permissions "
                         + " WHERE status = 'enabled' "
                         + " ORDER BY sectionName ";

            foreach (var i in db.getData(sql, null, r => new SystemPermissions()
                                                           {
                                                                 sectionName = r["sectionName"].ToString()
                                                               , permissionKey = r["permissionKey"].ToString()
                                                               , permissionValue = r["permissionValue"].ToString()
                                                           }
                                           )
                    )
            {
                permissionList["sectionName"] = new[] {i.sectionName};
                permissionList["permissionValue"] = new[] {this._BinToInt(i.permissionValue).ToString()};

            }
        }

    }

    class SystemPermissions{
        public string sectionName;
        public string permissionKey;
        public string permissionValue;
    }

}
```

How can the same thing be done using c#?

Comment: [Behold the Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have you tried to google `c# key value` ?

Answer (score 3):

> How to I create an array in C# by defining the key and the value of each entry?

In .NET that would be the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) class. For example:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary["foo"] = "bar";
dictionary["baz"] = "bazinga";
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am clear on this. But how would I define the multidimensional array where the section_name id the first key and the privilege_key is the second and that location = privilege_value?

Comment: The key of a dictionary could be any object. For example you could have a custom object with 2 properties: Key1 and Key2.

Comment: Then will it be `dictionary["foo"] = new someCustomClass(){key1= "section_name", key2 = "privilege_value"}` ?

Comment: In your example you used a custom class for the value which is also possible.

Comment: I have updated my question to show how the final array needs to look like

Comment: Oh, that would simply be a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`. For example: `var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()` and then in order to assign a value: `dictionary["section_name"] = new[] { "accounts", "account_phones", ... }`. So basically in your example the outermost Array is the containing dictionary where the key is a string and the value is a string array.

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing this correct, can you please check out this other post as I explained what I have done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733329/how-to-use-dictionary-class-in-c-sharp-to-have-2-objects

Comment: I am sorry, I had the wrong output listed in my question. I just updated my question with the correct Array. I appreciate it if you give me a code example.

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can use a `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("a", "c");
dictionary.Add("c", "d");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)